# Disable Button placed inside an ASP.NET template upon click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I hava an ASP.NET Web Forms application.

My goal is to disable the submit button `btnFinish` upon user click, in order to avoid multiple submits.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
CausesValidation="true" CommandName="MoveComplete" CssClass="buttonStyle"/>
```

The **Javascript** function is:

```
 function Validate(btnFinishId) {

            btnObj = document.getElementById(btnFinishId)

            if (Page_IsValid) {
                btnObj.disabled = true
            }
            else {
                 alert('Page has some validation error');
                 }

            // this is to prevent the actual submit
            e.preventDefault();

            return false;
    };
```

`btnFinish` is placed within a `FinishNavigationTemplate` in a ASP.NET Wizard Control.
Therefore, in order to avoid runtime errors, I need to get the `ClientID` of the control programmatically and then add it to the `OnClientClick` event of the button:

```
Button btFinish = MyWizard.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID$btnFinish") as Button;

if (btFinish != null){
   btFinish.Attributes.Add("onclientclick", "Validate('" + btFinish.ClientID + "');");
}
```

But it does not work. I use **Firebug** to check the page rendered by the browser but although the source code looks perfect, upon click the **Javascript** function is **not executed**.

If in the **Javascript** function I replace `Validate(btnFinishId)` with `Validate()` and instead of using the code behind to add the `OnClientClick` I write:

```
 <asp:Button OnClientClick="Validate();" "ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
    CausesValidation="true" CommandName="MoveComplete" CssClass="buttonStyle"/>
```

The function is executed but of course does not do what I want, because the button Id is missing. Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    validate = function(btn){

        //trigger client-side validation
        var valid = Page_ClientValidate("");

        //disable the button if the form is valid
        btn.disabled = valid;

        //trigger postback if the form is valid
        //otherwise do nothing
        return valid;                        
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" Text="Finish" OnClientClick="return validate(this);" OnClick="btnFinish_Click" ... />
```

It looks kind of backwards, but you could shorten the function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    validate = function(btn){
        btn.disabled = Page_ClientValidate("");                        
        return btn.disabled;                        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! I lost one day looking for a solution! I usually use MVC and jQuery hence when I have to modify an ASP.NET Web Forms with Javascript I really get frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a normal HTML button on your page, add attach a click event with jQuery.
You can then hide the .net button using css.

In the click event for your html buttom, you can all the .net buttons click event.

```
$("#yourbutton").trigger("click");
```